# How do I get the screen on my PC to appear on my TV screen? What do my settings need to be?

Tags: external-display

I have Screen A and Screen B.  My PC shows screen A, while my TV shows Screen B.  Oddly enough, Screen A is hidden on the left side of my TV screen.  How do I get Screen A to show on both TV and PC?  If I pull it to the right on the TV, it disappears on my PC and visa versa.

Comment: Did you set the second screen to mirror the first or be an extended display?

Comment: press `Win + P` then choose `Extend`

Answer (score 0):

For the same output on both displays, press Windows key + P and click Duplicate. Or right click on the desktop, click "Screen resolution", and in "Multiple displays" choose "Duplicate these displays". Your current setting gives you two separate screens and allows you to move windows between both displays freely, which is why one disappears when you move it to the TV.